# How to set candy icon theme for every app icon in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes

I installed Candy Icon theme on my Ubuntu 22.04 and after enabling it in gnome tweaks, some apps haven't changed their icons (e.g. Brave Web Browser, Spotify). It's confusing, because some third party apps actually have changed their icons on those from Candy Icon.

How do I make it so every app has their icons changed to those from Candy Icon?

Comment: Well, you need to provide an icon for every single "app" there is. Good luck with that.

Comment: You have to work with the developer of the icon theme to make an icon for every app you need.

Comment: But there are icons for every app i have, they are in the icon theme folder, they just don't load properly